# Could not build service builder (Maven) in Liferay7

Tags: maven, liferay, liferay-7

I created a service builder in eclipse ide (ga3.1.1). I selected build tool as Maven. The project created successfully as can be seen below.  But could not build and gives an error which is shown in the below image. Can anyone help me out?
[image]

Comment: Have you seen https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/using-maven-in-liferay-ide and https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/maven?

Comment: @RussBohl Yes bro i have installed the respective plugins